# Materialize Css Tooltip shows only when onclick

Tags: html, css, material-design

I need to show the tool tip when i click.This is my code.Please help me on this

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="tooltipped info_circle" data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Numbers should MUST be 5 digits. Nothing more, nothing less"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a JSFiddle demo to show the issue? Would be easier to help :)

Comment: Your question and description says contrasting points. Please ask the question clearly and have you tried this in jsfiddle?

Comment: Do you want to show the tooltip when you click or hover? Please correct it in the question.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Thulasinathan/1pLhok61/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <a class="btn tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Numbers should MUST be 5 digits. Nothing more, nothing less">Hover me!</a>
```

Also, check out the compatibility of your browser with the Materialize CSS

You could also try the '**onmouseover**' event.

[Materialize tooltip reference link](http://materializecss.com/dialogs.html#tooltip)

Comment: I added output image which i get as results. And i need to show this tool tip when i onclick the "a" tag

Comment: Try using onmouseover event as per directions given for onclick event in the documentation page of Materialize CSS.

Comment: It already working like "onmouseover" event only. I need when i click the tag "a" the tooltip need to show

Comment: No problem. use an onclick event on the element which should trigger the event. Use the following code `$('element').on('click',function(e){ e.preventDefault();
    $('element').tooltip({delay: 50});
  });`

Comment: Its not working.I used this $('.info_circle').on('click',function(e){ e.preventDefault(); $('.info_circle').tooltip({delay: 50}); });

Comment: I would recommend that you refer the JavaScript method of implementing Materialize components.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution for version 1.0.0, probably it may work in earlier ones. You should initialize the tooltip when you click on the button (event onclick), and on the event onmouseleave destroy the instance.

**Example for JQuery:**

```js
$('.tooltipped-click').click(function() {
  $(this).tooltip();
  $(this).tooltip('open');
});
    
$('.tooltipped-click').mouseleave(function() {
  if ($(this).tooltip()){
    $(this).tooltip('destroy');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script> 


<a href="javascript:;" class="tooltipped-click info_circle btn" data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Numbers should MUST be 5 digits. Nothing more, nothing less"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Click Me!</a>
```

**Example for pure Java Script:**

```js
function createTooltip(){
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltipped-click');
  var options={enterDelay: 50};
  var instances = M.Tooltip.init(elems, options);

  var instance = M.Tooltip.getInstance(document.getElementById("button"));
  instance.open();
}
function destroyTooltip(){
  var instance = M.Tooltip.getInstance(document.getElementById("button"));
  if (instance){
    instance.destroy();
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script> 


<a href="javascript:;" id="button" onclick="createTooltip();" onmouseleave="destroyTooltip();" class="tooltipped-click info_circle btn" data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Numbers should MUST be 5 digits. Nothing more, nothing less"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Click me!</a>
```